# Incrementing partial PK

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
INSTRUCTIONS:
  RecipeID
  Step
  ...
```

`RecipeID` is generated by another system. There does not need to be an explicit foreign key relation for `RecipeID`. As I insert steps into `Instructions` for a particular recipe, I would like `Step` to increment. When adding steps to a new recipe `step` should be back at 0 like so:

```
RecipeID | Step
---------------
    0    |  0
    0    |  1

RecipeID | Step
---------------
    0    |  0
    0    |  1
    0    |  2

RecipeID | Step
---------------
    0    |  0
    0    |  1
    0    |  2
    1    |  0
```

How would I generate this type of behavior?

Comment: How are you inserting the records?  What type of application is the front-end UI?

Comment: asp.net mvc web application. I COULD do it manually.. Is there no such way for SQL-Server to perform this behavior alone?

Comment: It could but it starts getting stupidly complicated. For instance what if you wanted to reorder the steps through an insert or delete. This is just a list of painful bugs waiting to happen don't do it. RecipeStepID as a PK. then and index on RecipeID and StepNumber is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this
Your own question indicates it's a poor idea.
How can you have a partial key?
By definition a partial key cannot be unique.

The only thing you need from step is an order, Displaying them (or querying them out with say Row_number) as 0 to n is trivial.

Think about what you would have to do, to insert a step you missed, or swap them...

RecipeStepID ( as surrogate primary key)

RecipeID,StepNumber as an index

Any foreign key links to the table use the surrogate key

Then re-ordering is just messing about with StepNo

Never seen the apprioach you are trying not turn into a disaster, and I can count the number of times it didn't start as a disaster without taking my mittens off.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: See notes at the bottom.  I wouldn't necessarily recommend using a trigger.**

You can use an `instead of` trigger to alter the values of `step` that will be inserted:

```
Create Trigger Instructions_UpdateSet
  On [Instructions]
  Instead of Insert
AS
BEGIN
  insert instructions
  select
    i.recipe,
    coalesce(ii.maxstep, -1)
      + row_number() over (partition by i.recipe order by i.step),
    i.instruction
  from inserted i
  left join (select recipe, max(step) as maxstep from instructions group by recipe)
    ii on i.recipe = ii.recipe
END;
```

This should seamlessly handle insertion of a single or multiple records.  If you do insert multiple records in a single query, you can supply a `step` value to indicate the order of the incoming inserted records, and they will be ordered appropriately and re-numbered to follow sequentially after the existing records.

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b13d5/1

---

Some things to note when using triggers in an application:

- It's very easy to forget about triggers because they hide very well.  Make sure to document them, or the next developer will be confused when the data they insert isn't the same in the database.
- If you are using a caching layer, make sure to refresh the cache after inserting records to pick up the changes caused by the trigger.
- In general, I would recommend avoiding triggers for business logic.  If you're looking for performance, it would be better to use a stored procedure, which is much more obvious about the intent and behavior.  Triggers are best suited for transparent operations like data validation, cascading updates/deletes, auditing, etc.

Comment: See as I said, complicated.